# Spray.io Hosting a Site (Swagger)

Tags: spray, swagger-ui

I've built a web service using Spray and have its specification in a swagger compatible JSON file.
How can I host the swagger-ui site on spray-can?
I've seen some samples that use redirects and others that use a "site" setting in the configuration file but I haven't been able to find a complete example that I can refer to.

Ideally I want to be able to have my site at...

```
api.mydomain.com
```

and all my services live on paths extending this URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for here...

https://github.com/mhamrah/spray-swagger-sample/blob/master/src/main/scala/SampleServiceActor.scala